# getPerspectiveTransform on a non entire quadrangle

Tags: android, image, opencv, image-processing, transformation

I am working on a Open CV Android project, the aim is the user can take a picture of a snooker table and I have to find balls positions on image retrieved. When I have four corners of the table on my picture, it is pretty easy, I have already coded table, balls and colors detection, and I use getPerspectiveTransform() function to warp my table on a rectangle. Then I have balls center position on the rectangle.

[image: source image]
[image: corners, center and color balls detection]
[image: perspective transformation]

If I have three corners, I think I have to extend table edges and find lines intersection to get my fourth corner.

Problem : With two corners, I am trying to find a solution for 2 weeks and I am not sure it is possible. I have the edge table dimensions (L=2.80m, l=1.40m) and balls diameter (d=61.5mm)

[image: ???]

I am not asking for a code solution (even if it's still better), but if someone have a way to resolve that problem, it would be very nice.

Comment: build a full quadrangle from the corner up to the first white dot on both sides.

Comment: in general it is not possible to build a perspective transform from 3 (or even 2) points since there are 2-4 degrees of freedom left: perspective transform has 8 dof.

Comment: Thank you for answer, it is a good idea, but now the problem will become to track little white dot, as you can see on the picture, edges color table are very influenced by the light. So if the white dot is in a bright area it wiil be difficult to track it...