# Inverse 0 and 255 of a matrice in Java OpenCv

Tags: java, opencv

Next to my topic ( [getPerspectiveTransform on a non entire quadrangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29181863/getperspectivetransform-on-a-non-entire-quadrangle) ), I'm finding a way to track little dots white on edges table in most of cases. If I use binary threshold, it works only if I choose arbitrarily the threshold. Problem is that edges color table are very influenced by the light. So I decided to convert my image on HSV and use InRange function which keeps only pixels which are between values my program determines (I adapt theses values based on mean value of edge table (brown in most of cases...)). This function returns a matrice where pixels between the range are set to 255, else 0.

I want to inverse this matrice, I mean switch pixels with val=0 to 255 and pixel with val=255 to 0. Here is my simple code (it doesn't work, it does nothing) :

```
for (int i=0; i<mat.rows(); i++){
    for (int j=0; j<mat.cols(); j++){
        if (mat.get(i,j).get(0)[0] == 0){
            mat.put(i,j,255);
        }
        else {
            mat.put(i,j,0);
        }
    }
}
```

If someone know how to do that in **JAVA**, it would be nice.

Comment: Can you provide the `mat` object Class?

Comment: I guess you have already tried `mat = 255 - mat`?

Comment: mat class is Mat from OpenCV library. Yes and i was aware it works with C++ but not with Java...

Comment: Set the `type` parameter in [threshold](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/imgproc/Imgproc.html#threshold(org.opencv.core.Mat,%20org.opencv.core.Mat,%20double,%20double,%20int)) to be `THRESH_BINARY_INV` (and `max` to `255`, of course).